# How do you use the Firebase Admin SDK to determine the experiment variant for a user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin, firebase-ab-testing

I have an A/B experiment and I would like to programmatically determine which experiment variant a user falls into on our backend. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API for Firebase Remote Config / A/B Testing to determine what specific experiment a user falls into. The only Admin APIs for Remote Config are for creating configuration sets.

The closest you can get is having each device write the value it gets from Remote Config, either Analytics or into a cloud database (such as Firestore or Realtime Database) and then accessing that information there.

Comment: Is there any plan on adding such a feature in the API ? It would be a handy thing to have